# Trying to use Selenium to use the search bar and select an option

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get a user to input their city and entering in onto [weather.com](https://weather.com/). Currently, I have selenium inputting the city onto the search bar, but I'm having trouble trying to get it to select an option as shown in the picture.

[image: Weather picture]

**My current code**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://weather.com/")
search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "SearchInput--InputField--1UoCv Search--inputClass--1FEhl")
city = input("Enter a city")
search.send_keys(city)
```

I think the element I'm trying to grab is also wrong, as here is an issue I get after running the code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Richard\Documents\GitHub\sunset-predictor\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    getInfo()
  File "c:\Users\Richard\Documents\GitHub\sunset-predictor\main.py", line 19, in getInfo
    search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "SearchInput--InputField--1UoCv Search--inputClass--1FEhl")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".SearchInput--InputField--1UoCv Search--inputClass--1FEhl"}
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.160); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF70BFD82B2+55298]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BF45E02]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE005AB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE4175C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE418DC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE7CBC7]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE620EF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE7AAA4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE61E83]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE3670A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BE37964]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF70C350AAB+3694587]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF70C3A728E+4048862]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF70C39F173+4015811]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF70C0747D6+695590]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BF50CE8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BF4CF34]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BF4D062]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF70BF3D3A3]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFCA2CF7344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFCA3F226B1+33]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause of the issue:** Below line is incorrect. Class name seems to have multiple classes(`SearchInput--InputField--1UoCv Search--inputClass--1FEhl`).

`find_element` method expects only a single class name and not multiple classes.

```
search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "SearchInput--InputField--1UoCv Search--inputClass--1FEhl")
```

**Solution:** In cases like these where there are multiple classes in the `@class` attribute in HTML, do not use `By.CLASS_NAME`, instead use any other locator strategy like `By.ID`, `By.XPATH` etc.

In addition, always use selenium's [waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) to effectively locate web elements.

**Working code below:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://weather.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15) # create wait object which wait for 15s based on the condition

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "truste-consent-button"))).click() # Click on Agree and Proceed button

search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='SearchInput--InputField--1UoCv Search--inputClass--1FEhl']")))
city = input("Enter a city")
search.send_keys(city)
time.sleep(20)
```

**Console:**

```
Enter a citymic test 123

Process finished with exit code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some waits for the driver to locate the specific elements. You might use the **Explicit waits** for this.

Though the `class` name of the element might be throwing error, using the `ID` of the element was able to perform the task. Below is the code that I tried.

```
# Imports required
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://weather.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Wait for the search box
search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"LocationSearch_input")))
print(search.get_attribute("class"))
# Click on the search box before sending text
search.click()
search.send_keys("India")

# Wait for all results to appear
results = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='LocationSearch_listbox']/button")))
# Click on the first result
results[0].click()
```